# Django: static files returning 404 error

Tags: python, django, static

I want to be able to load my static files on my local server, but when I request them, the browser returns 404 for every resource.

From what I can understand, `STATIC_URL` is the url in which my static files will be served. And `STATICFILES_FINDERS` specifies how my static files will be discovered. I set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to search for the `static` directory at the project root, but it doesn't seem to be be finding it.

On my `settings.py`,

```
# Python 2.7.5, Django 1.6

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

This is my directory structure:

```
.
|-- myapp
   |-- settings.py
   |-- ...
   static
   |-- images
   |-- javascript
   |-- stylesheets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1. You need a server for your static files. Are you using Apache HTTP server? The easiest way to serve your static files is to alias them in the `httpd.conf` file:

   ```
   Alias /static/ /path/to/static/
   <Directory /path/to/static>
   Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
2. You need to specify a `STATIC_ROOT`, which could be `/path/to/your_project/static` but then you probably want to put your current static files and folders somewhere else, because everything in `STATIC_ROOT` will be overwritten when you call `manage.py collectstatic`. I put all of my static files, such as Bootstrap, Tablesorter, images and icons in a folder called `assets`, then put `assets` in my `STATICFILES_DIR` list.
3. Use `manage.py collectstatic` to collect all static files and put them in `STATIC_ROOT` so that Apache can find them. Static files for the admin site will be automatically copied even if you do *not* add them to the list of `STATICFILES_DIR`.

Check out this [post](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2014/07/django-from-development-to-production.html) I wrote, which has several links to Django documentation on the topic.

Comment: The trailing slashes for the Alias directive should be balanced on the arguments when at a sub URL. That is use, 'Alias /static /path/to/static' and not 'Alias /static/ /path/to/static'. If they aren't, it can screw up how Apache maps URLs to the file system with the slash being dropped and the calculated path being wrong. This can result in either a Not Found or Forbidden HTTP error response depending on Apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton! I have edited the answer to balance the trailing slashes in the URL and the path. This particular example is from the [Django how-to guide for using Apache with mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) and the trailing slashes are correctly balanced as you indicated. Thanks again!